# Crapy error IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: scrapy

This is my code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from thuctapsinhvietnam.items import ThuctapsinhvietnamItem


class ThuctapsinhvietnamSpider(Spider):
    name = "thuctapsinhvietnam"
    allowed_domains ["thuctapsinhvietnam.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.thuctapsinhvietnam.com/thuctap-phuong-vinh-hao-3970.html"
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        def parse(self, response):
        cases = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="areaThongTinCaNhan"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr')

        for case in cases:
            item = ThuctapsinhvietnamItem()
            item['Name'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            item['Phone'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            item['Email'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            item['Dob'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            item['Sex'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            item['School'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            item['Introduction'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            item['Place'] = question.xpath(
                '//td[3][@class="thongtin"]/text()')extract()[0]
            yield item
```

I have problem when try to scrapy in ubuntu, I use xpath to get data.
I am trying scrapy information from this website but it has error here:

```
File "thuctapsinhvietnam_spider.py", line 15
cases = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="areaThongTinCaNhan"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr') 
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two of these:

```
def parse(self, response):
     def parse(self, response):
```